# Whenever I call the Activity, the app crashed and gives an error

Tags: java, android, crash

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ();
DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference ();
ListView listView;
List<String> ListString = new ArrayList<String> ();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layout.activity_main22);
    ListString.add ("Hello");
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener (new ValueEventListener () {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = dataSnapshot.child ("User");
            for(DataSnapshot s: snapshot.getChildren ())
                Toast.makeText (MainActivity.this, s.getKey ().toString (), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    listView = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.listview);
    ListAdapter listAdapter = new ListAdapter (MainActivity.this, ListString);
    listView.setAdapter (listAdapter);
    DatabaseReference s = databaseReference.child ("User");
    DatabaseReference p = s.child ("Name");
    p.setValue (ListString.get (1));

} }
```

As I said whenever I call this activity it crashes the app and the logcat is

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{lifeline.learn.com.attendencemarker/lifeline.learn.com.attendencemarker.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2984)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1518)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
>                                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1

Answer (score 0):

This line Causes the error

```
p.setValue (ListString.get (1));
```

You have only one value in ListString and you access 2nd value change it to below

```
p.setValue (ListString.get (0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like the error is saying `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1`you are tying to access index 1 or a list of size one. Remember counting starts at zero so change `p.setValue (ListString.get (1));` to 
`p.setValue (ListString.get (0));`

Answer (score 0):

This line is where the crash is:

`p.setValue (ListString.get (1));`

At this point, ListString has only one element.  A List object has zero-based indices.  So, when you tried to access index `1` that is the **second** element in the list, not the **first**.  So, what you really needed was:

`p.setValue (ListString.get (0));`